# Regex FullName Pattern

Tags: c#, regex

Tried looking around for a regex pattern for a full name and just can't seem to find one.

Ideally would match like

```
Tom Franklin
tom Franklin
tom franklin
tom franklin-jones
```

i.e. allow 1 space in the middle and some basic hyphens etc but thats all. Does any one know how to do this ?

**Edit: Including**

```
René Hadron van der Ööps
```

Comment: Mr. O'Brien will be disappointed that his name is invalid ;)

Comment: Mr. O'Brien needs a first name :P but yeah 2nd name is valid!

Comment: Please don't limit what names you consider “valid” by crude regex. “Jim-Bob O'Reilly” are “René Hadron van der Ööps” only the start of it... there are *many* more characters and constructs present in people's names than you think.

Comment: @bobince, that's what I was trying to get at, though you did a better job.

Comment: This may make for useful reading: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `/([\p{L}'-]+) ([\p{L}'-]+)/` to catch all possible letter. Or `/([a-z'-]+) ([a-z'-]+)/i` to catch only ascii letters.

The group `([\p{L}'-]+)` means `[\p{L}'-]` repeated at least one time. And `\p{L}` means any unicode *letter*. The `-` at the end means that "-" is allowed in names.

**Note :**
When you capture characters with `[]` the hyphen must be either at the start of your characters set or at the end.

---

**Edit :**

Mr. O'Brien is happy now.

---

**Resources :**

- [regular-expressions.info - unicode](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop)
- [regular-expressions.info - character sets](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

Comment: thanks colin. yeah im using C# - doesnt like \w and \s - gives me "unrecognized escape sequence"

Comment: @Tom remember to escape the \ either by writing "\\s" or @"\s"

Comment: It's not C# Tom - it's you. You must escape your backslashes or prefix the string with @ ie: string pattern = @"\w";

Comment: In this code you can't really detect "René Hadron van der Ööps" because you don't really know what is his firstname or lastname, plus I didn't use the \s, I suggest you to use it for the lastname.

Comment: err i seem to be getting a bug with the space ? i.e. seems even it i enter "tom jones" - still gives me my errore text "space is required"

Comment: What regex did you use ? It worked for me with `@"([\p{L}'-]+) ([\p{L}'-]+)"` on http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Answer (score 0):

\w+\s+[a-zA-Z-]+

Comment: hi gamebit - thanks for the response. i'm using ascii and when I enter that - doesnt like \w and \s - gives me "unrecognized escape sequence"