# How to parse name, phone number email from name card after using google cloud vision OCR? Android

Tags: android, parsing, google-cloud-vision

I finally successfully got the name card content by using google cloud vision API (OCR).
My question is, I stored all the content in a TextView, how can I get the name and phone number, and email from it? any idea to grab the most important detail I want from the String? thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to parse the JSON response and find the fields you want but i'm pretty sure you already know that, so what is your question ?

Comment: My question is that the name cards have a lot of styles depending on the design,how will you detect which text is belong to name, phone, email. I already known that email and number can be done by Macher.find. But how about name?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702737/regex-fullname-pattern

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385701/regular-expression-for-first-and-last-name

Comment: Unfortunately it's not that easy as with email and for example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want to extract and identify certain data from a card, using Google Cloud Vision API.

You've been able to obtain the data via OCR, but the problem is rather how to identify this data as there are an unlimited number of styles and structures for cards.

As @Inga as mentioned in the comments, you can try with regex expressions, although this could become harder the more styles and structures that you want to consider.

So I would also suggest you to consider using a Machine Learning approach.

For example, take a look at this article about [Parsing Structured Documents with Custom Entity Extraction](https://towardsdatascience.com/custom-entity-extraction-e966e00f6f47). It makes use of Google Cloud Vision API to read the data, same as you; but then it uses [Google Cloud Natural Language API](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/analyzing-entities) to identify certain elements via Entity Extraction.

Take a look at the [Natural Language Entity's description](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/reference/rest/v1/Entity#Type) to see what kind of elements you can identify with this feature, for example Names, Phone Number and Adress.

The same way, if this feature doesn't match all the data that you need to identify, you can also consider the option of [creating and training a custom AutoML Natural Language model](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/models) for the specific type of data that want to extract. The article mentioned earlier also makes use of this to identify specific data from restaurant's menus.

You might as well also consider taking a look at [Google Cloud Document AI](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/ocr) which also offers OCR features oriented to Document analysis.